# What is the difference between C# Thread.Sleep() and threadreference.Join()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-2.0

What is the difference between C# Thread.Sleep() and threadreference.Join()?

Answer (score 11):

Sleep is a method which suspends a thread for a period of time.  It acts on a single thread.

Join is a method which suspends a thread until another thread has finished.  It can be configured to sleep infinitely until that thread completes or for a finite period of time or until the other thread completes.  This is a method for synchronization between multiple threads.

Answer (score 5):

Sleep causes the current thread to sleep for the specified amount of time. Join will wait (block) the current thread until the referenced thread completes.